# is configuration space an H-space?

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Let $X$ be a manifold. Let $F(X,n)$ be the configuration space of order $n$. Let $B(X,n)=F(X,n)/\Sigma_n$ be the unordered configuration space of order $n$.

Is $B(X,n)$ an H-space?

Under what conditions on $X$ will $B(X,n)$ be a H-space?

Note: if $B(X,n)$ is a H-space, then the homology and cohomology are dual Hopf algebras, which is important.

Comment: Why do you want to know if everything is an $H$-space? Also, you may want to figure your last question out still.

Comment: Doesn't look like it, because of the fundamental group being non-commutative (for $n\geq 3$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Olivier Begassat says in the comments, this will typically not be true because the fundamental group will typically fail to be abelian. For example, when $X = \mathbb{R}^2$, the fundamental group is the braid group $B_n$, which is nonabelian for $n \ge 3$.

(In any case there isn't an obvious candidate for an H-space structure.)